How Can I Custom format the "Current XML Path" in NPP XML Tools Plugin
Want to : (with [@android:id='@com.google.android.qq:id/action_bar_root'])

/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout[@android:id='@com.google.android.qq:id/action_bar_root']/android.widget.FrameLayout[@android:id='@android:id/content']/androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout[@android:id='@com.google.android.qq:id/more_drawer_container']/android.widget.FrameLayout[@android:id='@com.google.android.qq:id/slim_status_bar_player_container']/android.view.ViewGroup[@android:id='@com.google.android.qq:id/navigation_bar_divider_frame']/android.widget.FrameLayout[@android:id='@com.google.android.qq:id/accessibility_layer_container']/android.view.ViewGroup[@android:id='@com.google.android.qq:id/next_gen_watch_container_layout']/android.view.ViewGroup[@android:id='@com.google.android.qq:id/next_gen_watch_layout_no_player_fragment_container']/android.widget.FrameLayout[@android:id='@com.google.android.qq:id/watch_player']/android.view.ViewGroup[@android:id='@com.google.android.qq:id/player_overlays']/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[@android:id='@com.google.android.qq:id/skip_ad_button']/android.widget.LinearLayout[@android:id='@com.google.android.qq:id/skip_ad_button_container']/android.widget.TextView[@android:id='@com.google.android.qq:id/skip_ad_button_text']

current version :

/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.TextView

source xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.widget.FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:enabled="true" android:layout_height="3120px" android:layout_width="1440px" android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="0px">
  <android.widget.LinearLayout android:enabled="true" android:layout_height="3120px" android:layout_width="1440px" android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="0px">
    <android.widget.FrameLayout android:enabled="true" android:layout_height="3120px" android:layout_width="1440px" android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="0px">
      <android.widget.LinearLayout android:enabled="true" android:id="@com.google.android.qq:id/action_bar_root" android:layout_height="3120px" android:layout_width="1440px" android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="0px">
        <android.widget.FrameLayout android:enabled="true" android:id="@android:id/content" android:layout_height="3120px" android:layout_width="1440px" android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="0px">
          <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout android:enabled="true" android:id="@com.google.android.qq:id/more_drawer_container" android:layout_height="3120px" android:layout_width="1440px" android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="0px">
            <android.widget.FrameLayout android:enabled="true" android:id="@com.google.android.qq:id/slim_status_bar_player_container" android:layout_height="3120px" android:layout_width="1440px" android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="0px">
              <android.view.ViewGroup android:enabled="true" android:id="@com.google.android.qq:id/navigation_bar_divider_frame" android:layout_height="2965px" android:layout_width="1440px" android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="102px">
                <android.widget.FrameLayout android:enabled="true" android:id="@com.google.android.qq:id/accessibility_layer_container" android:layout_height="2965px" android:layout_width="1440px" android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="102px">
                  <android.view.ViewGroup android:enabled="true" android:id="@com.google.android.qq:id/next_gen_watch_container_layout" android:layout_height="2965px" android:layout_width="1440px" android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="102px">
                    <android.view.ViewGroup android:enabled="true" android:id="@com.google.android.qq:id/next_gen_watch_layout_no_player_fragment_container" android:layout_height="2965px" android:layout_width="1440px" android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="102px">
                      <android.widget.FrameLayout android:contentDescription="影片播放器" android:enabled="true" android:hint="㩒兩下就可以顯示控制項" android:id="@com.google.android.qq:id/watch_player" android:layout_height="809px" android:layout_width="1440px" android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="102px">
                        <android.view.ViewGroup android:clickable="true" android:contentDescription="展開迷你播放器" android:enabled="true" android:focusable="true" android:id="@com.google.android.qq:id/player_overlays" android:layout_height="809px" android:layout_width="1440px" android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="102px">
                          <android.widget.RelativeLayout android:enabled="true" android:layout_height="809px" android:layout_width="1440px" android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="102px">
                            <android.widget.FrameLayout android:enabled="true" android:layout_height="809px" android:layout_width="1440px" android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="102px">
                              <android.widget.RelativeLayout android:enabled="true" android:layout_height="809px" android:layout_width="1440px" android:layout_x="0px" android:layout_y="102px">
                                <android.widget.FrameLayout android:clickable="true" android:enabled="true" android:focusable="true" android:id="@com.google.android.qq:id/skip_ad_button" android:layout_height="168px" android:layout_width="262px" android:layout_x="1178px" android:layout_y="617px">
                                  <android.widget.LinearLayout android:contentDescription="略過廣告" android:enabled="true" android:id="@com.google.android.qq:id/skip_ad_button_container" android:layout_height="112px" android:layout_width="234px" android:layout_x="1178px" android:layout_y="645px">
                                    <android.widget.TextView android:enabled="true" android:id="@com.google.android.qq:id/skip_ad_button_text" android:layout_height="71px" android:layout_width="108px" android:layout_x="1220px" android:layout_y="665px" android:text="繼續"/>
                                    <android.widget.ImageView android:enabled="true" android:id="@com.google.android.qq:id/skip_ad_button_icon" android:layout_height="56px" android:layout_width="56px" android:layout_x="1328px" android:layout_y="673px"/>
                                  </android.widget.LinearLayout>
                                </android.widget.FrameLayout>
                              </android.widget.RelativeLayout>
                            </android.widget.FrameLayout>
                          </android.widget.RelativeLayout>

.....
The "XPath Expression Evaluation" is another function, can't solve my problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Do you want the generated XPath to include predicates that specify the value of the android:id attribute?
I think you should be able to do this by adding android:id to the "Identity attribute names" list in the "options" dialog.
